# US: What is the purpose of "club" in retail outlets

Tags: business

I'm thinking of:

- BJ's Wholesale
- Sams Club
- Costco

Does a member/club relationship legally confer some business advantages?

Is it true that that they are not public access stores, because you must be a current member and you have to show credentials at the entry point?

Could a club deny particular services (even to a member) that an ordinary business may not?

Comment: Some background: http://www.npr.org/sections/money/2015/09/25/443519599/episode-653-the-anti-store  This explains why they chose to be member's only clubs - to entice people to do more of their shopping at one place, to make the membership "worth" it. But that doesn't discuss legal advantages.

Comment: It streamlines the record keeping of sales tax exempt resellers

Comment: Not that any of the big 3 would do this, but could it legally exempt them from the federal requirements imposed on "public accommodations?"